# Rails page has wrong html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, routes, scaffolding, function

I have a link to a page in the same folder as this page on my rails site:

```
<%= link_to 'Special Access', 'followers/special_access' %>
```

However, when I go to this page it shows a different page on that url.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div id="sent">
    <p>Your request has been sent</p>
    <%= link_to 'Home', followers_path %>
</div>
```

I tried deleting the page  that the html is from, but first of all I need that page and it also gives me an error.

I edited the controller to contain:

```
def special_access
    format.html  { redirect_to followers/special_access }
    format.json  { render :json => @post }
end
```

instead of

```
def show
```

but that still didn't solve the problem.

How do I get the right html to show up on the right page?

Comment: show your `config/routes.rb` or `rake routes` output

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused about how routing works in rails. Post your `config/routes.rb` so we can see what's going on.

Comment: L13::Application.routes.draw do
    get "saccessp/index"

    resources :followers
    get "followers/index"
    root :to => 'followers#index'
    root :to => 'saccesp#index'

Comment: I think the error is 'stack too deep' or sth similar. It's because you've got infinite loop in special_access method by redirecting to self over and over again. First of all get rid of redirection cause you are already in.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not define a route for `special_access`, rails will just assume the the `special_acces` part in the path is the `:id` of the route for the show page (as the urls look like `followers/:id`).

So first off, in your `routes.rb`, find the `resources :followers` and replace with the following:

```
resources :followers do
  collection do
    get :special_access
  end
end
```

And now you should best always use the rails path helpers, so your link would become

```
<% link_to 'Special Access', special_access_followers_path %>
```

Here I was assuming the special access is on the collection of the followers, if it should be on a specific follower (which seems more logical to me, but I have no idea of course), you should write

```
resources :followers do
  member do
    get :special_access
  end
end
```

And your link would become

```
<% link_to 'Special Access', special_access_followers_path(@follower) %>
```

I am not quite sure what you want to do in your controller action, I hope you just want to render an html page (because redirecting to the same url seems silly, and your syntax is wrong there too).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The page I'm trying to get to displays a table of the followers, but I don't want it to be of a follower itself.

Comment: Ok, so it is on the collection. Did you try this? Did you have any problems with it? Is something unclear? This should work.

Comment: I think it worked but I am now getting a "no method" error in special_access.html.erb. It does not recognize "each" in: <% @followers.each do |follower| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= follower.Name %></td>
    <td><%= follower.Email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', follower, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

Comment: Then `@followers` is most likely nil. Do you set it in your controller?

Comment: `def new
    @follower = Follower.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @follower }
    end
  end`

Comment: `  def index
    @followers = Follower.all`

Comment: But do you set it in the `special_access` method? Because only that is executed.

Comment: You are asking me? If you are expecting `@followers` is set in the view, as obviously, you get that error. I hope you know what `@followers` should contain. All followers, some followers, some followers of something specific. You should set it to something in the `special_access` method, for instance like you do in the `index` method. If you do not get that, it could really help to read a basic book about Rails. That is the cornerstone. Instance variables which are set in the controller-action, are usable in the rendered view. But you have to set them. HTH.

Comment: `  def special_access
    @followers = Follower.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @followers }
    end
  end
end`

Comment: That looks good to me, except it will render `special_access.html.erb` (cfr. your comment). Do you still have a problem with it?

Comment: You still get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`? That should mean the variable `@followers` is still not set. You can easily display the value of `@followers` for debugging in your view, add `<%= @followers.inspect %>` before calling the `each`.

Comment: Yes, it is working now, but in the table the link to remove a follower: `<%= link_to 'Remove', :method => :delete %></td>` does not do anything. It is also displaying the information of each follower above the table.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer. How much questions do you want me to answer? Did you try google how to write a `link_to` to remove a link? Did you ever read a book about rails? This is all such basic stuff.